# Dynamic cron based on model value

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.4, cron, dynamic

I made a simple custom CRUD module.

My table have 4 columns: id, name, action, schedule.

Action is a select where I can select a controller.

Schedule is a text field where I can store for example: * * * * *.

This means that every row I add in the table can have a different sheduled time.

```
id | name | action              | schedule
1  | abc  | Path\To\CronScript1 | 0 0 * * *
2  | bca  | Path\To\CronScript2 | 0 2 * * *
```

**I would like Path\To\CronScript1 to be executed every day at midnight**

**and Path\To\CronScript2 to be executed every day at 2am.**

Cannot find any reference online.
Any suggestion will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use crontab compatible schedule you can see implementation Magento logic in cron schedule model

`\Magento\Cron\Model\Schedule::trySchedule` and `\Magento\Cron\Model\Schedule::matchCronExpression`

```php
        $match = $this->matchCronExpression($e[0], $time->format('i'))
            && $this->matchCronExpression($e[1], $time->format('H'))
            && $this->matchCronExpression($e[2], $time->format('d'))
            && $this->matchCronExpression($e[3], $time->format('m'))
            && $this->matchCronExpression($e[4], $time->format('w'));
```